# Import data using JPA keeping same identifiers

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've developed a simple web app which use some database tables using JPA. Let's say Table A and Table B with reference to Table A. My app runs in different environments on my customers like development, testing and production stage. Because of that I have to create a process to export/import data between these environments.

When I move the objects I want to keep the same ID because I want to keep the same references. Is there any way to do that with JPA?

I am using Hibernate 4.3.8 with Oracle Database. This is my Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Category
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

And I am trying to do that:

```
Category category = new Category();
category.setId(1L);
category.setName("Test");

EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.getEntityManager();
em.merge(category);
```

But it uses the hibernate sequence to generate the ID instead of using the given one. If I use `persist` instead of `merge` it throws an exception because it is a detached object.

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: One would have thought that an "import process" would use an SQL import script, and use the "javax.persistence.XXX" property to import it

Comment: Hi Neil, it is a process of export and the import. If I use an SQL import script I should generate it on the export side. Is there any way to do that with JPA?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define a custom id generator using a defined sequence

You need a class which extends `org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator`:

```
package yourPackage;

public class CustomGenerator extends SequenceGenerator
{
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And to use your custom generator in your entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CustomGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "CustomGenerator",
        strategy = "yourpackage.CustomGenerator",
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "custom_id_sequence")
        })
private Long yourId;
```

Comment: Hi Matteo! Thanks for your answer. I just want to use the defined id during the import process. Otherwise it should use the sequence or the default generator strategy. So the strategy should be like " id == null ? generate : this.id". Do you agree ?